# How does square-rooting this inequality work?

Tags: inequality

I have the inequality $(x + 3)^2 \le (y + 3)^2$. I tried square-rooting the inequality and getting the two inequalities $x + 3 \le y + 3$ or $y \ge -x -6$.

This is wrong, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Note, for example, that $0^2\le(-1)^2$, but $0>-1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong because\begin{align}a^2\leqslant b^2&\iff\sqrt{a^2}\leqslant\sqrt{b^2}\\&\iff\lvert a\rvert\leqslant\lvert b\rvert\\&\iff-\lvert b\rvert\leqslant a\leqslant\lvert b\rvert.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is equivalent to $$(x+3)^2-(y+3)^2\le 0$$

$$(x+3-y-3)(x+3+y+3)\le 0$$
$$(x-y)(x+y+6)\le 0$$

Now consider different cases and find solution regions.